# System Volume Controls Act Like Low Pass Filter

Tags: sound, alsa, realtek, volume-control, hda-intel

I can't seem to get volume to work correctly on my built in laptop speakers on my ASUS Zephyrus M16. If I open AlsaMixer, the master and speakers channels don't actually control volume, they act like a low pass filter, so the audio just gets more muffled as I turn it down. PCM works, and I'm thinking about setting the volume controls to that, but I'd like to change the actual amplitude if possible. The chip I have is a Realtek ALC285 and the card is "HDA Intel PCH". Any advice? It works fine over the headphone jack.

Comment: Please could you edit to add what version of Ubuntu you’re using? Thank you.